# Which groups embrace unix.SE?

Tags: discussion

So the Ubuntu community, and some of its leaders, have embraced ubuntu.SE so well that it's now an impressive success. Is there a distro (or some other Unix/Linux community) that (semi)officially recognizes and promotes unix.SE?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, no distros or major *nix communities promote us. [AU](https://askubuntu.com/) is a special case; as far as I know no other SE site has "official" support like they do, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. I'm fairly confident that's also the reason we didn't end up getting force-merged with them back at the beginning; their semi-official recognition from Canonical is a big deal

Comment: Are you sure about that last point? Wasn't it more due to the opposition (the vote)?

Comment: @Tshepang That's why we didn't merge originally, but from my understanding the SO team was considering merging us anyway (that's what I meant by "force-merged"), and AU being adopted by Canonical was the reason they didn't. For example, [this comment by Jeff on the SO blog](http://so.mrozekma.com/blog.png) (I got the impression later that the October announcement he was talking about was the whole AU/Canonical thing, and it would make sense)

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from a "Stack Overflow Inc" point-of-view, we have not been approached nor heard of any other distro embracing or asking for any sort of official support through unix.stackexchange.com as Canonical/Ubuntu initiated.

Answer (score 2):

There was a proposal to create an [archlinux-focused SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7470/arch-linux) that has been closed. Developers, moderators and users of archlinux [were not fond of this proposal](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102759).

I do not believe unix.SE needs an official sponsor. Actually, this may be a bad thing if only one or two distros officially moved their support on unix.SE: imagine if 50% of the questions were about gentoo, or opensuse, or XYZ... I would feel less confident to ask a generic unix/linux question.

Comment: To be fair, AU didn't go over great on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591890) either, but those things are to be expected

Comment: I don't agree that partnership(s) are a "bad thing." Companies that recognize the value of our community will relinquish a bit of control to give their users a better product. Those that want to maintain complete control, wont. Microsoft (http://techie-buzz.com/tech-news/msdn-stack-overflow.html) and Goolge Android (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html) have both partnered with Stack Exchange and it hasn't harmed the diversity of those sites. More questions for a distro simply means more questions for the site. It doesn't de-value *other* contributions.

Comment: @Robert This Microsoft and Android thing is interesting (exciting). Is there meta question or blog post about these 'big' sorts of associations?

Comment: Here is the MSDN announcement: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-results-featured-in-msdn-search/. I couldn't find one about the Android relationship, except for the official announcement I linked above: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html

Comment: @Robert Cartaino Partnerships are great, don't get me wrong, but do you think it would have been the same if Microsoft had been the only company to partner with SO **at the beginning of SO**? I think that for a general site like SO or unix, you want to grow a large and diverse userbase before making these kinds of partnerships.